# Woocommerce checkout redirection not working as expected after few attempts

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, plugins

I am developing a WooCommerce payment gateway plugin with WordPress version 5.4.2 and WooCommerce version 3.8.0.

Plugin working fine for few 3-4 trials, but after this I am not able to get redirected to the checkout page. It keeps redirecting to the cart or basket page.

I have also checked the logs, but nothing found there.

I not professional in WordPress.

The plugin has [live demo](https://webdevco.in/sagar/atom/woocommerceTest/wordpress/)

You can see code below

```
// Submit payment and handle response
    public function process_payment($order_id) {
        global $woocommerce;
        global $current_user;
        //get user details   
        $current_user   = wp_get_current_user();

        $user_email     = $current_user->user_email;
        $first_name     = $current_user->shipping_first_name;
        $last_name      = $current_user->shipping_last_name;
        $phone_number   = $current_user->billing_phone;
        $country        = $current_user->shipping_country;
        $state          = $current_user->shipping_state;
        $city           = $current_user->shipping_city;
        $postcode       = $current_user->shipping_postcode;
        $address_1      = $current_user->shipping_address_1;
        $address_2      = $current_user->shipping_address_2;
        $udf1           = $first_name." ".$last_name;
        $udf2           = $user_email;
        $udf3           = $phone_number;
        $udf4           = $country." ".$state." ".shipping_city." ".$address_1." ".$address_2." ".$postcode;

        $user_email     = $_POST['billing_email'];
        $first_name     = $_POST['billing_first_name'];
        $last_name      = $_POST['billing_last_name'];
        $phone_number   = $_POST['billing_phone'];
        $country        = $_POST['billing_country'];
        $state          = $_POST['billing_state'];
        $city           = $_POST['billing_city'];
        $postcode       = $_POST['billing_postcode'];
        $address_1      = $_POST['billing_address_1'];
        $address_2      = $_POST['billing_address_2'];
        $udf1       = $first_name." ".$last_name;
        $udf2       = $user_email;
        $udf3       = $phone_number;
        $udf4       = $country." ".$state." ".shipping_city." ".$address_1." ".$address_2." ".$postcode;

        $order          = new WC_Order( $order_id );
        $atom_login_id  = $this->login_id;
        $atom_password  = $this->password;
        $atom_prod_id   = $this->atom_product_id;
        $amount         = $order->get_total();
        $currency       = "INR";
        $custacc        = "1234567890";
        $txnid          = $order_id;    
        $clientcode     = urlencode(base64_encode(007));
        $datenow        = date("d/m/Y h:m:s");
        $encodedDate    = str_replace(" ", "%20", $datenow);
        
        if(!function_exists('wc_get_checkout_url')){ 
            require_once '/includes/wc-core-functions.php'; 
        } 

        $ru = wc_get_checkout_url(); 

        $data["login"] = $atom_login_id;
        $data["pass"] = $atom_password;
        $data["prodid"] = $atom_prod_id;
        $data['txnid']=$txnid;
        $data['amt'] = $amount;
        $data['reqHashCode'] = $this->req_hash_code;
        
        $data['requestEncypritonKey'] = $this->req_enc_key;
        $data['salt'] = $this->req_salt_key;
       
        $signature = $this->getChecksum($data);

        $param = "login=".$atom_login_id."&pass=".$atom_password."&ttype=NBFundTransfer"."&prodid=".$atom_prod_id."&amt=".$amount."&txncurr=".$currency."&txnscamt=0"."&clientcode=".$clientcode."&txnid=".$txnid."&date=".$encodedDate ."&custacc=".$custacc."&udf1=".$udf1."&udf2=".$udf2."&udf3=".$udf3."&udf4=".$udf4."&ru=".$ru;
        $param = $param."&signature=".$signature;
     
        $atomenc = new AtomAES();
        $encData = $atomenc->encrypt($param, $data['requestEncypritonKey'], $data['salt']);

        global $wpdb, $woocommerce;
        return array('result' => 'success', 'redirect' => $this->url."?" ."login=".$atom_login_id."&encdata=".strtoupper($encData));
        exit;
    }


// checking response from payment gateway and show messages on checkout page
function check_atom_response(){
        global $woocommerce;
        global $wpdb, $woocommerce;
     
        $atomenc = new AtomAES();
        $decrypted = $atomenc->decrypt($_POST['encdata'], $this->res_enc_key, $this->res_salt_key);
        $array_response = explode('&', $decrypted); //change & to | for production
        
        $equalSplit = array();
        foreach ($array_response as $ar) {
            $equalSub = explode('=', $ar);
            if(!empty($equalSub[1]) && !empty($equalSub[0])){
                $temp = array(
                    $equalSub[0] => $equalSub[1],
                );
                $equalSplit += $temp;
            }
        }
     
        
        if(isset($equalSplit['f_code']) && $this->validateResponse($equalSplit)){
            
            $order = new WC_Order($equalSplit['mer_txn']);
          
            $order_id = $equalSplit['mer_txn'];
            $VERIFIED       =   $equalSplit['f_code'];
            if($VERIFIED == 'Ok'){
                $VERIFIED = 'complete';
            }else{
                $VERIFIED = 'pending';
            }

            $bank_name      =   $equalSplit['bank_name'];
            $bank_txn       =   $equalSplit['bank_txn'];
            $discriminator  =   $equalSplit['discriminator'];

            if($equalSplit['f_code']=='Ok'){
                $order->update_status('completed');
                $this -> msg['message'] = "Thank you for shopping with us. Your account has been charged <b>Rs".$equalSplit['amt']."</b> for order id <b>".$order_id."</b> and your transaction is successful. Bank Transaction ID is  : <b>".$equalSplit['bank_txn']."</b>.";
                $this->msg['class'] = 'woocommerce-message';
                $this->msg['order'] = $order;
            } else if($equalSplit['f_code'] == 'F') {
                $return_url = $this->get_return_url($order);
                $order->update_status('failed');
                $this->msg['class'] = 'woocommerce-error';
                $this->msg['message'] = "<b style='color:red;font-size:20px'>The transaction has been failed or declined.</b>";
                $this->msg['order'] = $order;
            } else {
                $order->update_status('cancelled');
                $this->msg['class'] = 'woocommerce-error';
                $this->msg['message'] = "<b style='color:red;font-size:20px'>The transaction has been cancelled or declined.</b>";
                $this->msg['order'] = $order;
            }
            add_action('the_content', array(&$this, 'showMessage'));

            add_filter('cron_schedules', 'new_intervals');
            function new_intervals($interval) {

                $interval['minutes_30'] = array('interval' => 30*60, 'display' => 'Once 30 minutes');

                return $interval;
            }
            function InitiateMyCron() {
                wp_schedule_event(time(), 'minutes_30', 'update_ransaction_status');
            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: Please share your code, else we won't be able to help you

Comment: You can see my code where I created logic to create encrypted string to get redirected to the payment page and get response back on WordPress site.

Comment: @jrswgtr can you help me with this ??